# string.match() evaluates to null in IE 8 only

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have some working JavaScript code which runs perfectly in other browsers but **don't work with IE 8**. It's actually simple piece of code and I really can't figure out what's the problem?

In short, `while` part never gets executed in IE (`d.match(pattern)` is always **null**), in all other browsers I'm getting correct offset.

```
var ids = new Array(),
    d = o.innerHTML,                  // gets correct HTML code in all browsers
    pattern = /id="subblock_(\d+)"/,
    p;

while (d.match(pattern) != null) {

  // IE never gets here!
  p = d.search(pattern);
  ids[ids.length] = d.match(pattern)[1];
  d = d.substr (p+14);

  }
```

Value of **d** variable looks like this

```
<div id="subblock_0">...</div>
<div id="subblock_7">...</div>
<div id="subblock_59">...</div>
```

Not sure, it looks quite correct to me but obviously Microsoft again doesn't agree with me.

Note: I have tried with IE 8 and last updates of Firefox, Chrome and Opera!

Comment: Does `subblock_[0-9]+` give another result ?

Comment: Why are you pulling out the ids from innerHTML? Are you sure the value of `d` is the same in IE?

Comment: @X.L.Ant Nope, does the same.

Comment: @epascarello It's part of much complex code, I need these numbers in array for later use.

Comment: Just saying there are other ways to get the elements.

Comment: @epascarello I know, but most of it is not my code and I have not time right now to rewrite everything. It's just a small fix ;)

Comment: Dont you have to escape the quotes? `id=\"subblock_(\d+)\"`

Comment: @pherris no, regex pattern isn't a string (it's object). I actually had to remove them or just fix pattern for IE ("?) to make it work, like epascarello said in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am too lazy to start up a VM, but if I remember right IE8 does not return quotes. A simple console.log(d) would verify that.

```
pattern = /id="?subblock_(\d+)"?/,
```

Comment: YES, that was it! I didn't notice that while watching output of **d** value. Thanks a lot, it was killing me last couple of hours.